# Opening new form in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, forms

In one of my form classes, inside of a button click event, I need a new form to be opened. This is my code;

```
Private Sub btnEditReservation_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnEditReservation.Click


    Dim ResultResSearch As New SearchResultDiag
    Dim DbAccess As New SQL
    Dim SQLString As String
    Dim Result(,) As String
    Dim sDate, sTime As String

    Select Case CaseIDTY
        Case 1
            SQLString = "SELECT Reservation.DateTime, Reservation.GuestName, [Table+Reservation].TableID FROM Reservation INNER JOIN [Table+Reservation] ON Reservation.ReservationID=[Table+Reservation].ReservationID WHERE Reservation.DateTime LIKE '" & DTPickerEDT.Text & "%'"
            Result = DbAccess.Read_Array_DB(SQLString)
            If Result.Length = 0 Then
                ErrorNotFound()
                Exit Sub
            End If
            For i = 0 To (Result.Length / 3) - 1
                sDate = Mid(Result(i, 0), 1, 10)
                sTime = Mid(Result(i, 0), 10, 5)
                ResultResSearch.ReservationResult.Rows.Add(sDate, sTime, Result(i, 1), Result(i, 2))
            Next

        Case 2

        Case 3

        Case 4

    End Select

    ResultResSearch.ReservationResult.Visible = True
    ResultResSearch.Show()

End Sub
```

I declare the form I want to open 'Dim ResultResSearch as new SearchResultDiag', and use the '.show()' function.

When debugging, and clicking the event handle, nothing happens whatsoever. I ran through the code line by line and everything seems to work except for 'ResultResSearch.Show()'

Ive tried changing the shutdown mode to when the last form is closed.

Any help would be appreciated!! :) Thanks!

Comment: When you say 'nothing happens', does the debugger get into this method? If so, does it get past 'Result.Length = 0' condition?

Comment: Place a breakpoint on the `ResultResSearch.Show()` line and see if it's hit.

Comment: Yep, it hits the ResultResSearch.Show() line. Ive looked into the propertes of the new form and it all seems to be okay? It hits the line - continues without erros but does not show the form! :(

Comment: Ok, and if you add a breakpoint in ResultResSearch's Shown method, does it get there?

Comment: Yep, it gets into the method.

Comment: At the Shown breakpoint, can you see the form? I.e. is something closing it as quickly as it is opening?

Comment: Yikes. This looks scary-vulnerable to SQL injection issues. It's time to learn about parameterized queries.

Answer (score -1):

You just have to do SearchResultDiag.show() & me.hide()(to hide current form). Not sure if the thing you are creating will work.. You don't have to declare the form you want to open

Comment: You don't _**have**_ to close the current form. And besides, declaring a new instance of the form is better practice.

Comment: Please, I'm not _"bitching"_ at your solution. But I gave you a heads up that declaring a new form is better practice. But as I read it I got the feeling that you were saying he was supposed to use it. But no, it doesn't matter if he does or not.

Comment: Alright no worries. I'm sorry about my comment. I just tried to help. Did not see Andrew's comment..

Comment: I understand you were trying to help, and so was I. I'm not posting a solution since I believe Andrew's comment is it, that's why I referred to it.

Comment: You're right indeed in that you do not need to declare a new form every time. Everything will still work as expected, but it's a good thing to do if you use `.ShowDialog()`.

Comment: Indeed that might be true.. It might be recommended, but personally I did not have to use it for now. It can happen in the future, and now I know how to :)